# Multiple optional parameters: it is possible to use different order?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, optional-parameters

I have a method with 4 optional parameters and I would like to use any possible combination in my code including only the first and the last one.

Here is an example:

```
public void Method(int a = 5, string b = "foo", bool c = true)
{
    ...
}
```

And I would like to do this:

```
Method(6, false);
```

However, when I am trying to use only these two parameters, I am gettting an error, that I can´t convert string to bool. Is there a way how to solve this problem without overloading? I don´t want ot use overloading, because I would have to create around 15 methods with all possible combinations.

EDIT: And I don´t want to use

```
Method(a: 6, c: false);
```

because I find it a little bit annoing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

You just need to add the parameter names to your arguments to indicate which one you are passing the arguments to:

```
Method(a: 6, c: false);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this option to my question. I would like to avoid this, because I find it annoying. Is there a different way?

Comment: @vejvodma How else are you going to tell the compiler which argument corresponds to which parameter?

Comment: @vejvodma IIRC, one of the reasons why named arguments are added was to help with optional arguments like this. Why do you find it annoying? It increases the readability by a lot if you name your parameters correctly.

Comment: I have a different types for every argument and most of them are enums, so it is actually preatty easy to read.

Comment: @vejvodma well, this is the only possible way as far as I’m concerned...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will make some a few overloads for the most used combinations and then I will use Method(a: 6, c: false).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create 2 different functions with the same name for different parameter orders.

Function one:

```
public void Method(int a, string b, bool c)
{
    ...
}
```

Function two (with only 2 parameters):

```
public void Method(int a, bool c)
{
    ...
}
```

Your IDE compiles your code and will know which function to use

Comment: Well, thats just overloading. I have 4 parameters in my method and I would like to use any possible combination, so I would have to create much more methods than only 2.

Comment: I just showed you a possible way to extract your program logics automatically to two different functions. Your program would use these funcitons automatically in consideration which parameters you are using. If you want to use one time these parameters and another time others then you wont find another way like Sweeper you already shown with Method(a: 6, c: false);

Comment: I aprreciate your help, however in my case overloading is not the best (or easiest) way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this if you run into issues if you *have* to define each parameter:

```
Method(a: 6, b: "undefined", c: false);
```